# Datepicker not working in higher versions of android

Tags: android

I am learning android programming and have developed a small application which includes 2 datepickers on the same screen(start and end date).

It works on android version 2.3 but crashes when i set the date in android version 4.4.

Below is the java code snippet.

public class WriteExcelActivity extends Activity {

```
   private TextView startDateDisplay;
    private TextView endDateDisplay;
    private Button startPickDate;
    private Button endPickDate;
    private Calendar startDate;
    private Calendar endDate;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

    private TextView activeDateDisplay;
    private Calendar activeDate;


   @Override 
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_writeexcel); 

        /*  capture our View elements for the start date function   */
        startDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fromdate);
        startPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        startDate = Calendar.getInstance();

        /* add a click listener to the button   */
        startPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDateDialog(startDateDisplay, startDate);
            }
        });

     /* capture our View elements for the end date function */
        endDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.todate);
        endPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

        /* get the current date */
        endDate = Calendar.getInstance();

        /* add a click listener to the button   */
        endPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
           showDateDialog(endDateDisplay, endDate);
     }
        });

        /* display the current date (this method is below)  */

    updateDisplay(startDateDisplay, startDate);
    updateDisplay(endDateDisplay, endDate);
    }

    private void updateDisplay(TextView dateDisplay, Calendar date) {
        dateDisplay.setText(
                new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(date.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1).append("-")
                    .append(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).append("-")
                    .append(date.get(Calendar.YEAR)).append(" "));
            }

    public void showDateDialog(TextView dateDisplay, Calendar date) {
        activeDateDisplay = dateDisplay;
        activeDate = date;
        showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
    }

    private OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override


        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            activeDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            activeDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            activeDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateDisplay(activeDateDisplay, activeDate);
            unregisterDateDisplay();
        }
    };

    private void unregisterDateDisplay() {
        activeDateDisplay = null;
        activeDate = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, dateSetListener, activeDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), activeDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), activeDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
        super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(activeDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), activeDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), activeDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                break;
        }
    }



@Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); 
    return true; }
```

Appreciate if anyone can point out the mistake.Thanks

===========================================

## xml.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       android:id="@+id/toDate"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" >



  <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textbox_fromdate" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:text="@string/txt_textbox_fromdate"
         android:layout_marginTop="22dp" />



 <TextView
          android:id="@+id/fromdate"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/textbox_fromdate"
     android:ems="10"
   />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fromdate"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fromdate"

    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_datepicker"
     />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textbox_todate" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:text="@string/txt_textbox_todate"
       android:layout_below="@+id/fromdate" />


 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/todate"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/textbox_todate"
     />


  <Button
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/todate"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/todate"

    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_datepicker"
    android:contentDescription="" />




 <Button
     android:id="@+id/btnexcel"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/todate"
     android:onClick="onClickWriteExcelData"
     android:text="Write excel data" />



</RelativeLayout>

enter code here
```

Comment: In the logcat what is the crash?

Comment: I am copying the apk file to the phone for installing and running. Hence not sure where to see the logcat messages. The device does not appear in the android studio..so had to do it this way...

Comment: You will have a hard time to solve this without the logcat output. Have you tried getting it via command line (adb)? Check this: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this,it should work.

```
public void onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker view, int year,int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
```

Comment: Thanks chandra, but it still gives the same error.  It says the app has stopped working

Comment: can you post your xml code also so that it will be easy to figure out.?

Comment: Do not call the unregisterDateDisplay(); method because it nullify the textview and calender object.that why it generating NPE.